# Does the size of Firefox window launched by Selenium Webdriver can throw an Exception?

Tags: firefox, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to execute a Test on monster.com. 
The problem is when i run the code the Webdriver always launches a small window and because of that some time I get org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException exception.

I had used `window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` statement to wait till the page is completly loaded.

I am asking this question "Does the size of Firefox window launched by selenium webdriver can give an Exception?" because sometime after running the code i waited till 16/18 sec but when I  see that the page is not loading then i maximize the size of the window in the very same running code and it worked without throwing ElementNotVisibleException exception.

If you want I can post the code that I use.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ideally window size does not matter unless your element does not contains any such type of css or attribute which makes it enable only after maximizing the window. You should check the css attributes manually after maximizing the window and then analyze the changes. If its changed then yes it depends.

Comment: @Shantanu - I was not able to add comment there so I posted a new answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am going through the css attribute. As soon as i post the video i will send you a link for that